# Dynamic component does not bind properly

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-ui-angular2

In our Angular 2 application we use the Combobox component from Kendo. This component is wrapped into a component created dynamically during the runtime. The code of the creation is very simple :

```
let factory = this.resolver
        .resolveComponentFactory(ComboboxComponent);

nextTo.createComponent(factory);
```

The `nextTo` variable represents where Angular has to create the component.

```
@ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef })
container: ViewContainerRef;
```

The `container` variable represents a `div` in the HTML Template.

**NB** : the component is created during the `ngAfterViewInit` event. No errors are thrown during the creation.

The Kendo component is properly instanciated and initialized, but when we affect data after the creation, the component seems to don't recognize the binding, and do nothing. Any ideas ?

HTML of the component :

```
<kendo-combobox [data]="listItems"></kendo-combobox>
```

TypeScript :

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: `combobox.component.html`,
    selector: 'combobox',
    styleUrls: [
        'combobox.component.css'
    ]
})
export class ComboboxComponent extends FieldComponent {
    public listItems: Array<string> = ["X-Small", "Small", "Medium", "Large", "X-Large", "2X-Large"];
}
```

**NB2 :** `FieldComponent` is an abstract class we use for global actions for all of our components.

**EDIT1** : I finally manage to find what's the problem, but I can't say what's wrong. When I inspect the DOM, I can see that a `<div role='combobox'>` is hidden, and this is the combobox which contain all data. So why have I a second combobox shown with no data ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what cause this strange behavior. Due to the very first beginning of the project, we use Kendo JQuery for our components, and we use `kendo.all.js`. I don't really know why, but it seems that `kendo.all.js` interfers into the `kendo-combobox` HTML template of the new Angular component, and it inject some intempestive HTML which cause the strange behavior.

Comment: This is due to our [Web Components](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/third-party/webcomponents) integration.

Both web components and Angular use same name for custom tags/component selectors.

Comment: Yeah I see ;-) Maybe should you notify this ugly issue in documentation or somewhere else ? I think similar projects like ours which want to migrate components would face the same issue ...

Comment: Actually Web Components support is already removed from the _*.all_ bundle . Upgrading to newer version of the scripts should remove this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that change detection for the component is not triggered in this case.
`createComponent` returns a [ComponentRef](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentRef-class.html) which has the change detector associated with that component. You can try calling [detectChanges()](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ChangeDetectorRef-class.html#!#detectChanges-anchor) of that *ChangeDetectorRef* once the dynamic component is created.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I've already tried this with no success. I Wonder why I have to do this ! Angular does this automatically ...

Comment: Can you demonstrate the scenario? I've tried to replicate the behavior in [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/b1qCb9jvkGhMRgYrMlGV?p=preview), but all seems to work. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Hey, after some investigation I have a clue. See my edit in my post, thanks !

Comment: @ChristopheGigax I'm running out of ideas what might be the reason for this. Could you modify the plunkr so that it replicates the behavior? This will help me to track down the cause.

Thanks!

Comment: I've found the cause of the side effect, I'll post a response.